How to move vertices on surface height
I beveled some edges and then moved a set of vertices with the help of the scale command to the inside of the structure to creat a certain kind of effect. Is there a way to bring the vertices to their original place again. Using scale doesnt work correct for some reason...Thank you in advance!



You could select this edge loop in the middle and just dissolve it with ctrl+X
Then add it again if you need it

the problem is that I wanted all the edge loops to be adjusted. This is too time consuming.

I found a solution that worked well for this case. I went into Edit Mode, selected all the vertices of the surface via the X-Ray tool and then used the Smooth Tool.
